# Запятая после "значит"

Tags: пунктуация

Из того же текста: "Но злоупотреблять его доверием — значит, жестоко оскорбить его". Разве после "значит" нужна запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед связкой «значит», присоединяющей сказуемое к подлежащему, ставится тире. После связки знак препинания не ставится:В свете идти на любовь – значит идти на верный обман. В. Соллогуб, Метель. Обижаться – значит признавать себя слабым.